# How to specify a certain place in a (CDS) weather data query?

Tags: python, netcdf, weather, grib

I am trying to get time series data for a specific place (latitude and longitude) for different weather elements from the CDS datapool. Therefore, I am using the `cdsapi` package and can run queries such as:

```
import cdsapi
import xarray as xr

# settings
filename = "here.nc"

# request
c = cdsapi.Client()
res = c.retrieve(
    "reanalysis-era5-single-levels",
    {
        "product_type": "reanalysis",
        "variable": "2m_temperature",
        "year": "2019",
        "month": "01",
        "day": "01",
        "time": [
            "00:00",
        ],
        "format": "netcdf",
    },
    filename,
)

nc = xr.open_dataset(filename, decode_cf=False)
df = nc.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=False)
print(df)
```

This can easily be extended to more time points, but not as easily to places (even the returned latitude and longitude coordinates sometimes do are unreasonable).  If I understand correctly the *netcdf* data is already interpolated, but there is no parameter to specify a distinct place (only `area` and `grid`). Because I have to query several places all over the world and want to go a few years back with hourly/daily resolution, querying large grids will not work.

Does anybody have an idea how to get the data for a specific place? If possible, I would like to keep my tooling Python only, but happy to use other packages or try other solutions.

Comment: I do not think there is an easy solution with the CDS api, however, there is a service that does just that, and it is free for moderate use, https://data.planetos.com/datasets/ecmwf_era5_v2 and there is also a possibility to access the data on AWS cloud, either using NetCDF or ZARR formats. https://registry.opendata.aws/ecmwf-era5/
I am related to both of these projects, feel free to delete the post if advertising these services is against some policy.

Comment: yes, the CDS is designed to retrieve gridded data then it's not possible to retrieve sparse data. So the options are: to download each point separately (slow) or to download the entire grid (1 month for 1 variable of ERA5 data is 1.4 GB) and then using xarray and dask extract the time-series. If you don't have storage I would explore the solutions written by @kakk11